# API building doesn't build with custom URL

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am building my API. When I launch it it in debug mode, it launches with the file:
launchSettings.json. It uses then the correct IP and port to launch.
[image: Launch with debug mode]

When I build the API and run the exe file it launches with localhost.
[image: Launching EXE]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it a case sensitivity issue? Is your settings file exactly named `LaunchSettings.JSON`?

Comment: no it is launchSettings.json My bad. I will edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the lanchsetting,json will just work when you debugging the application in visual studio. It will not affect the exe file.

If you want to run the exe to launch with specific IP address, I suggest you could try to use `UseUrls` method in the CreateHostBuilder method.

More details, you could refer to this codes:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls("http://172.17.12.63:5000");
            });
```

Result:

[image]